# Packet Filter for Windows 2003

Tags: windows, networking, windows-server, packet-capture

Using windows server 2003. I would like to drop packets payload that matches a certain format going to a specific application. Is there any software on the kernel level that can do this?

One of my solution was to put a proxy between the specific application and the user and dropped certain packets that matched a certain format but the problem with my approach is: the application now thinks that the proxy is the real client, making all logging data have the same **client ip**.